# GET data from database with ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I'm trying to mount data from my database with a componentDidMount. The problem is that it's not giving any response and showing the catch error in the console. I think my url might be incorrect? Anyone that could have a look?

url: ${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/challengedetail/:id

The error in the console: GET http://localhost:3000/challengedetail/:id 404 (Not Found)

---

```
import React from 'react'
import DefaultLayout from "../layout/Default"
import './Challengedetail.css'
import Responsechallenge from '../components/Responsechallenge'
import axios from "axios"
import TakeChallenge from "../components/Takechallenge"

class Challengedetail extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            title:"",
            description:"",
            responses: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        // debugger
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/challengedetail/:id`,
            withCredentials: true
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data)
            this.setState({
                title: response.data.title,
                description: response.data.description
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("Charles this is an ffffffffffferror: ", error)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
                <div className="challengedetailpage">
                    <div className="headercontainer">
                        <div className="challengesectionbox">
                            <h1>{this.state.title}charles</h1>
                            <p>{this.state.description}ffff</p>
                        </div>

                        <div className="takechallengebox">
                            <TakeChallenge/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="responsechallenges">
                        <Responsechallenge/>
                        <Responsechallenge/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </DefaultLayout>
        )
    }
}

export default Challengedetail
```

---

Allchallenges.js

```
<Link to={`/challengedetail/${challenge._id}`}>
                                        <Challengebox 
                                            key={challenge._id} 
                                            id={challenge._id} 
                                            title={challenge.title} 
                                            description={challenge.description}
                                    />
                                </Link>
```

Comment: When encoding a String, the following rules apply:

The alphanumeric characters "a" through "z", "A" through "Z" and "0" through "9" remain the same.
The special characters ".", "-", "*", and "_" remain the same.
The space character " " is converted into a plus sign "+".
All other characters are unsafe and are first converted into one or more bytes using some encoding scheme. So colon before your is unsafe. One more thing is you backend up and running as you are getting 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are calling a route that does not exist.

In other words, if the route looks like this in your back-end: `/challengedetail/:id`

then on your front-end, instead of `:id`, you would pass the dynamic value of `id` like so:

`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/challengedetail/${id}`

or statically it could look like this:

`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/challengedetail/123456789`

I cannot tell you exactly what id you need to pass, that depends on what you want to get from the database. In your case, it might be the `id` of `challengedetail`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I added some extra code in my question. It is the code that I am having in my main allchallenges file. Whenever a user clicks on a challenge the challengedetail page is opened. The problem that I am having now is that I don't have any challenge._id in my Challengedetail file, so I don't know how to call the dynamic value of id. Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: This seems to be a different question and now it all depends on how you structured your app. I believe that we found a solution to your problem in this particular question. Your new question is more of a passing data from one component to another in React. It does not seem that `Challengebox` is a child nor a parent of `Challengedetail`, so I'd assume that now you might need to use tools such as `Redux`. You might want to write a new question, asking specifically about that and outlining your app structure in more detail. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: thanks I'll ask another question. I gave you an upvote, please feel free to give me one as well. thanks